# Cordova plugin management in different environments

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am developing on windows, and this is my main way of working I have everything under source control but not the plugins folder. I want the plugins to be available when I pull onto another machine. Should I copy and paste the `fetch.json` into my other machine? and how do I get this to install the plugins?

What would be the normal way of developing cordova/ionic apps when it comes to plugin management in different environments.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past Ionic would manage this for you using `ionic plugin add` and `ionic state restore`, but these days Cordova has your covered. By using the `--save` flag with the `cordova plugin add` command, Cordova will save all the plugins to `config.xml`, this also works for platforms, so `cordova platform add ios --save`.

I am pretty sure that it will work the same way if you do `ionic platform add ios --save`. All you have to do on the other machine is `cordova prepare` to get all the plugins and platforms installed.

Ionic implemented the method using `package.json`, because at the time there was no good alternative, but Cordova has a good way to manage plugins now. There is a discussion about this [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/904).

Answer (score 0):

As @Dexter explains, adding plugins to `config.xml` via `cordova plugin add some-plugin --save` works great if you do a clean checkout and run `cordova prepare` - the plugins listed in `config.xml` will be installed as the versions specified in `config.xml`.

However, if you have an existing checkout with existing plugins installed, this will not update your plugins to versions specified in `config.xml`. It will only install any new plugins which have been added to `config.xml` since you last ran `cordova prepare`.

For example, if you have a local project in which `cordova-plugin-device@1.0.1` is installed and do a `git pull` which updates the `config.xml` to contain:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.4" />
```

If you run `cordova prepare`, the device plugin will not be updated to `v1.1.4`. To do this, you'd need to manually remove and re-add the plugin:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-device && cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

For this reason, I have created a couple of tools to help me with this scenario: using a combination of [cordova-check-plugins](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-check-plugins) and [cordova-plugin-config-command](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-config-command), you can insert a `<command>` element into `config.xml` which will sync the locally installed plugins with those specified in `config.xml`, including installing any that are missing and updating any whose version differs from the version specifed in `config.xml`.

For example, to automatically update installed plugins to match versions specified in the config.xml:

```
<command
    name="cordova-check-plugins"
    args="--target=config --update=auto --allow-downdate"
    hook="before_prepare"
    display_output="true"
    abort_on_error="true"
/>
```